# UITextView expands from top

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, uitextview

I am trying to expand `UITextView` in `textViewDidChange` :

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    int numLines = textView.contentSize.height/textView.font.lineHeight;
    if(numLines < 6)
    {
            CGRect frame = textView.frame;
            frame.size.height = textView.contentSize.height;
            textView.frame = frame;
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(int)textView.tag inSection:0];
            MessageDetailCell *cell = [tableMessageDetail cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.txtReplyHeightConstraint.constant = textView.frame.size.height;
            [cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
            [cell setNeedsLayout];
            [cell layoutIfNeeded];
    }
}
```

This does expand the `UITextView` but from the top. I want it to expand from the bottom. I have constraints applied on both the top and bottom of `UITextView`.

Comment: Try to change the priorities such that the top constraint has higher priority that the bottom constraint.

Comment: @dasdom : This certainly has some impact. I set the top constraint priority as 1000 and bottom one as 250. Now the subview above textView also moves up. The textView still expands from top though. Maybe I am doing something wrong priority wise.

Answer (score 0):

Remove bottom constraint and add width constant constraint. It will expands from bottom. Plz try this.

Answer (score -1):

We can do it with simple logic. Try the following and let me know its working or not.

```
view.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y - 10, view.frame.size.width, textView.contentSize.height + 10);
```

Here i used to increase the height by 10pt. You can change the value as per your requirement.

Comment: UITextView is binded by a constraint. I am using auto layout. This won't make a difference.

Comment: That is what I am trying. But the UITextView expands from top.